# Onclick displaying div as block is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display text if you click on a certain div.
But it is not working, I am also not getting errors?

```
<p class="activiteitInfo">
  <a class="fancybox-inline" style="color: #f3f3f3 !important;">Meer info</a>
</p>
<p class="activiteitReserveer">
  <a href="%3C?php%20echo%20$tijd;%20?%3E" style="color: #f3f3f3 !important;">Reserveren</a>
</p>
<div class="hoi" style="display: none;">
  <?php echo $meer_info; ?>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".activiteitenInfo").click(function () {
      $(".hoi").css("display", "block");
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

Comment: is your click event ever fired?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the element you are trying to listen to click events on has the class `activiteitInfo` not `activiteitenInfo` to which you are trying to listen in your javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, please use:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".activiteitInfo").click(function () {
      $(".hoi").css("display", "block");
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your element class is "activiteitInfo", and your looking for "activiteitenInfo".

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".activiteitInfo").click(function () {
      $(".hoi").css("display", "block");
    } );
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="activiteitInfo">
  <button class="fancybox-inline" style="color: #0003 !important;">Meer info</button>
</p>
<p class="activiteitReserveer">
  <a href="%3C?php%20echo%20$tijd;%20?%3E" style="color: #f3f3f3 !important;">Reserveren</a>
</p>
<div class="hoi" style="display: none;">
test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You are use wrong class name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".activiteitInfo").on('click', function() {
    $(".hoi").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```css
.activiteitInfo > a {
  color: blue;
  }
.activiteitReserveer {
  color: green;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="activiteitInfo"><a class="fancybox-inline">Meer info Click Me!</a></p>
<p class="activiteitReserveer"><a>Reserveren</a></p>
<div class="hoi" style="display: none;">
  Text
</div>
<script>
</script>
```